# Get <li> with specific keyword from HTML page - Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to extract a specific `<li>` from an HTML page based on the words that it contains in Python?

For example:
Let's take this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1916

I get the HTML of this page in Python like this:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
infile = opener.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1916')
```

And what I would like is to get each `<li>` that contains a given word. If I search 'verdun' I would like to have all the `<li>` and their content that have this word like

```
<li><a href="/wiki/February_21" title="February 21">February 21</a> – WWI: The <a href="/wiki/Battle_of_Verdun" title="Battle of Verdun">Battle of Verdun</a> begins in <a href="/wiki/French_Third_Republic" title="French Third Republic">France</a>.</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do like this,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print([i for i in soup.select('li') if 'verdun' in i])
```

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup allows you to search by partial text. Just do the following:

```
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
lis = soup.find_all('li', text=re.compile('verdun'))

# Now the lis contain a ResultSet (list) of all li tags with 'verdun' as text
for li in lis:
    print li.text
```